# merge statement error want to update few tables

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, rowid

Merge statement is showing error:

```
MERGE INTO costing.table1 USING
(SELECT table1.ROWID row_id,
        M.STRPS_MATERIAL AS STRPS_MATERIAL
   FROM costing.table2 p
   JOIN costing.table1 M
     ON p.MATNR = M.MATNR
    AND p.WERKS = M.WERKS
    AND p.BESKZ = M.BESKZ
    AND p.SOBSL = M.SOBSL
  WHERE M.SOBSL = '30') src ON (table1.ROWID = src.row_id )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET M.STRPS_MATERIAL = src.STRPS_MATERIAL;


SQL Error: ORA-00904: "table1"."ROWID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Help me in correcting the query as `rowid` is not the column present in the `table1`.

Comment: you can select ROWID even if it is not there in the column. My doubt is what is `costing` here and why didn't mention in the inner query? u can try M.ROWID instead of table1.ROWID.

Comment: costing is schema...

Comment: ok.Did ur inner query working fine?

Comment: M.ROWID !! what is M THERE??

Comment: Tabe alias. U gave `costing.table1 as M` in the join statement right?

Comment: INNER QUERY SHOWS THE SAME ERROR INVALID IDENTIFIER...

Comment: THANKS ..IT IS DONE,...THANKS ALOT

Comment: Glad I helped. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
MERGE INTO costing.table1 USING
  (SELECT M.ROWID row_id,
  M.STRPS_MATERIAL AS STRPS_MATERIAL
  FROM costing.table2 p
 JOIN costing.table1 M
 ON p.MATNR                                           = M.MATNR
 AND p.WERKS                                          = M.WERKS
 AND p.BESKZ                                          = M.BESKZ
 AND p.SOBSL                                          = M.SOBSL
 WHERE M.SOBSL                                        = '30'
 ) src ON (costing.table1.ROWID = src.row_id )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET M.STRPS_MATERIAL = src.STRPS_MATERIAL;
```

Comment: i want to upload data which have empty spaces in sql server but when i upload same in oracle it turns out to be null.


     the problem is my procedures has conditions to check for ' ' .
     so it will return no results.

as i m migrating my code from sql srver to oracle.